# Extending the comparable generic

Tags: java, generics, icomparable

I'm developing a template based classes in Java that implement various trees structure (such as standard binary tree, red-black tree or B-Tree). My idea is to have it done like various lists in Java Collections. That is one interface class which is then expanded by specified trees. However, I hit a wall with a strange problems:

```
BSTree.java:12: error: BSTree is not abstract and does not override abstract method     search(Comparable) in Tree
public class BSTree<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Tree {
       ^

BSTree.java:20: error: name clash: add(T#1) in BSTree and add(T#2) in Tree have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
    public void add(T key) throws NullPointerException {
                ^
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class BSTree
    T#2 extends Comparable<T#2> declared in class Tree

BSTree.java:28: error: method compareTo in interface Comparable<T#2> cannot be applied     to given types;
                if (key.compareTo(ptr.key) == -1) {
                   ^
  required: T#1
  found: Comparable
  reason: actual argument Comparable cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class BSTree
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable

BSTree.java:42: error: name clash: remove(T#1) in BSTree and remove(T#2) in Tree have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
    public void remove(T key) throws NullPointerException, TreeException {
                ^
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class BSTree
    T#2 extends Comparable<T#2> declared in class Tree

BSTree.java:49: error: method compareTo in interface Comparable<T#2> cannot be applied     to given types;
            if (key.compareTo(ptr.key) == 0) {
                   ^
  required: T#1
  found: Comparable
  reason: actual argument Comparable cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class BSTree
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable

BSTree.java:81: error: method compareTo in interface Comparable<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
            else if (key.compareTo(ptr.key) < 0) ptr = ptr.left;
                        ^
  required: T#1
  found: Comparable
  reason: actual argument Comparable cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class BSTree
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable

BSTree.java:89: error: name clash: search(T#1) in BSTree and search(T#2) in Tree have     the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
    public Node<T> search(T key) throws NullPointerException, KeyNotStoredException {
                   ^
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class BSTree
    T#2 extends Comparable<T#2> declared in class Tree

BSTree.java:94: error: method compareTo in interface Comparable<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
            if (key.compareTo(ptr.key) == 0) return ptr;
                   ^
  required: T#1
  found: Comparable
  reason: actual argument Comparable cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class BSTree
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable

BSTree.java:95: error: method compareTo in interface Comparable<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
            else if (key.compareTo(ptr.key) < 0) ptr = ptr.left;
                    ^
  required: T#1
  found: Comparable
  reason: actual argument Comparable cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class BSTree
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable
```

It looks like Java thinks that the object are of different types... How to fix that?

Here's piece of my code:

**Tree.java**

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    protected T key;
    protected Node parent, left, right;

    public Node(T key, Node parent) {
        this.key = key;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

}

public abstract class Tree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    protected Node<T> root;
protected Integer nodesCount;

    public abstract void add(T key) throws NullPointerException;

    public abstract void remove(T key) throws NullPointerException, TreeException;

    public abstract Node<T> search(T key) throws NullPointerException, KeyNotStoredException;
}
```

**BSTree.java**

```
public class BSTree<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Tree {

    public BSTree() {
        root = null;
        nodesCount = new Integer(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T key) throws NullPointerException {
        if (root == null) root = new Node<T>(key, null);    
        else {      
            boolean left = false;
            Node ptr = root, parent = ptr.parent;
            while (ptr != null) {
                parent = ptr;
                left = false;
                if (key.compareTo(ptr.key) == -1) {
                    ptr = ptr.left;
                    left = true;
                } else ptr = ptr.right;
            }

            if (left) parent.left = new Node<T>(key, parent);
            else parent.right = new Node<T>(key, parent);
        }

        nodesCount++;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(T key) throws NullPointerException, TreeException {
        /* implementation */
    }

    @Override
    public Node<T> search(T key) throws NullPointerException, KeyNotStoredException {
        /* implementation */
    }

}
```

EDIT:
Thanks to your pieces of advice I was able to reduce number of errors to 5. Here they are:
javac -d ../bin *.java

```
BSTree.java:28: error: method compareTo in interface Comparable<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
                if (key.compareTo(ptr.key) == -1) {
                       ^
  required: T#1
  found: Comparable
  reason: actual argument Comparable cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class BSTree
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable

BSTree.java:49: error: method compareTo in interface Comparable<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
            if (key.compareTo(ptr.key) == 0) {
               ^
  required: T#1
  found: Comparable
  reason: actual argument Comparable cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class BSTree
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable

BSTree.java:81: error: method compareTo in interface Comparable<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
            else if (key.compareTo(ptr.key) < 0) ptr = ptr.left;
                        ^
  required: T#1
  found: Comparable
  reason: actual argument Comparable cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation     conversion
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class BSTree
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable

BSTree.java:94: error: method compareTo in interface Comparable<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
            if (key.compareTo(ptr.key) == 0) return ptr;
                   ^
  required: T#1
  found: Comparable
  reason: actual argument Comparable cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class BSTree
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable

BSTree.java:95: error: method compareTo in interface Comparable<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
            else if (key.compareTo(ptr.key) < 0) ptr = ptr.left;
                        ^
  required: T#1
  found: Comparable
  reason: actual argument Comparable cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class BSTree
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable
```

Now, my code has `Node<T>` and `Tree<T>` where it lacked it. But what's still wrong?

Comment: You probably need to extend `Tree<T>`, not `Tree`...

Comment: Your edit with the new error messages does not have the matching code, so it's hard to tell, but it looks like `ptr` is still declared as `Node` instead of `Node<T>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you duplicating functionality in the JDK, you should read the code to get some ideas.

One thing your code needs to make your use of Node and Tree generic.

```
 public class BSTree<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Tree<T> {
```

and

```
protected Node<T> parent, left, right;
```

BTW: You shouldn't use a wrapper when you can use a primitive.

```
protected int nodesCount;
```

Comment: Also use `Node<T> ptr = root, parent = ptr.parent;` in the `BSTree#add(T)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the generic parameter on `Tree` in the `BSTree` declaration:

```
public class BSTree<T ...> extends Tree<T>
```

which means the `add(T)` method in `BSTree` doesn't override the one in `Tree` as it is, since they don't have the same parameter type.

However, since `T` *as a class* is not more precise than an `Object` (we only know it implements the `Comparable` *interface*), both methods have the same erasure as `add(Object)`, with potentially incompatible types (identified in the compiler's error output as `T#1` and `T#2`).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public class BSTree<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Tree<T> {
```